# Every day I get multiple files in different paths and want to copy each file to a specific folder within each path

Tags: powershell, copy

Every day 3 new CSV-files are sent to 3 different paths. I want to copy these files to an archive within each path and then run a script which removes the first line of each file. The resulting files are then moved to another folder where a batch reads them.

Example for a path1:     "Z:\Test\1\Script\Export1_2022-11-09.csv"
Example for an archive1: "Z:\Test\1\Script\Archive\Export1_2022-11-09.csv"

Example for a path2:     "Z:\Test\2\Script\Export2_2022-11-09.csv"
Example for an archive2: "Z:\Test\2\Script\Archive\Export2_2022-11-09.csv"

```
$Files = @( "Z:\Test\1\Script\Export1_2022-11-09.csv", "Z:\Test\2\Script\Export2_2022-11-09.csv")

$Files | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_ -Destination 
    (Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $_
}
```

The part where the first line of each file gets deleted works fine, but i can't think of a way to have each file copied to a specific and different path before.
I would very much appreciate some help.
Thank you in advance.

@Theo: I edited my Question because i made a mistake, the files have different names.

Comment: What is the point to first make a copy, then copy them and finally move them away again?

Comment: All files are named equal, so this: `The resulting files are then moved to another folder where a batch reads them.` will lead to filename collisions if that is one and the same destination for the three files..

Comment: @Theo I edited my question because i forget to include the files have different names. They always start with "Export1" or "Export2" and then have the exact timestamp added after. The archive paths are all different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you want is to save the original files in an Archive subfolder within the same path. Then rewrite the original file so the header line gets removed.

Use `[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName()` to split the path from the full path and filename string, then join it with 'Archive'

```
# if the file dates in their names are always todays date, 
# you should not hard code these, but instead create your array like:
# $today = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
# $Files = "Z:\Test\1\Script\Export1_$($today).csv", "Z:\Test\2\Script\Export2_$($today).csv"

$Files = "Z:\Test\1\Script\Export1_2022-11-09.csv", "Z:\Test\2\Script\Export2_2022-11-09.csv"

$Files | ForEach-Object {
    # construct the archive path
    $archivePath = Join-Path -Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_)) -ChildPath 'Archive'
    # create that folder if it does not already exist
    $null = New-Item -Path $archivePath -ItemType Directory -Force
    # copy the file as-is
    Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $archivePath

    # now remove the header line from the original file
    (Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $_

    # create a new path and filename to move the edited files to a specific folder where a batch can process them
    $basePath  = '{0}\Transfer' -f $_.Substring(0,[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_).LastIndexof("\"))
    $baseName  = ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) -split '_')[0]
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_)  # this includes the dot
    $finalPath = Join-Path -Path $basePath -ChildPath ('{0}{1}' -f $baseName, $extension)
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $finalPath -Force
}
```

Comment: The Archive Path already exists. This works perfectly so far.
The edited files shall be moved to folders with following paths "Z:\Test\1\Transfer" and "Z:\Test\2\Transfer" and so on. All destination folders are different.
I need to move each file to its specific folder and rename the file from "Export1_2022-11-09.csv" to "Export1.csv", so the batch can read the files.

Comment: @John919 Thanks for explaining. I have edited my answer to also include the move part

Comment: Hey Thank you for adding the lines at the end of the code. However if i try to run the script, it displays an error message: "move-item: illegal characters in the path" How can i fix that?
I think the part after childpath seems to be the problem i run into.

Answer (score 0):

Try following to get new filename

```
Files = @( "Z:\Test\1\Script\Export_2022-11-09.csv", "Z:\Test\2\Script\Export_2022-11-09.csv")
foreach($File in $Files)
{
   $lastIndex = $File.LastIndexOf("\")
   $baseFilename = $File.Substring($lastIndex + 1)
   $newFilename = $File.Substring(0, $lastIndex + 1)
   $newFilename += "Archive\" + $baseFileName
   Write-Host "New File Name = " $newFilename
}
```